# how to prevent to send ajax request while another ajax request is processing?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I work on an auto complete search box that search Database and return users that related to search.I use jquery ajax to do this.when `keyup` on input element occurred then I send a ajax request to the `/ajax/search/ url like below:

```
$("#search").keyup(function(){
    $(".itemSearch").remove();
    $(".notfound").hide();
    $("#searchResultSection").height("70px");
    if(!$("#search").val()){
        $("#searchResultSection").slideUp();
        $(".ajaxLogoSearch").hide();
        $(".notfound").hide();
    }
    else{
        var data = {
            query: $("#search").val()
        };
        $("#searchResultSection").slideDown();
        $(".ajaxLogoSearch").show();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ajax/search',
            data: data,
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(result){
                if(result.found==0){
                    $(".ajaxLogoSearch").hide();
                    $(".notfound").show();
                }
                else{
                    var searchResult = $("#searchResultSection");
                    $(".ajaxLogoSearch").hide();
                   searchResult.css({"height":20});

                    for(var i=0;i<result.users.length;i++){
                        var content = '<div class="itemSearch">\
                <img src="../../static/social/images/defaultMaleImage.png" height="50px">\
                <p>'+ result.users[i].firstname+ ' '+ result.users[i].lastname +'</p>\
            </div>'
                        if(searchResult.height() < 370){
                            searchResult.height("+=70px");
                        }
                        $("#innerSearch").append(content);
                    }
                    $(".itemSearch").hover(function(){
                        $(this).css({"background":"rgb(55, 108, 221)"});
                    },function(){
                        $(this).css({"background":"#658be6"});
                    });
                }
            }

        });
    }
})
```

My problem is when I type 2 letters immediately 2 ajax request sent and I see the search result twice in search result box.I want a way to prevent to send 2th ajax request while first is not completely done.How can I do this ?

EDIT:I finally find the solution in codeproject site thanks for your answers.
[this is thte link of the solution](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/573999/How-to-Abort-a-AJAX-Call-Before-Calling-the-Same-A)

Comment: What version of jquery are you using and do you use any spinner or animation while ajax request ?

Comment: @MinaGabriel my jquery version is 2.0.3 and I use a spinner in my code `$(".ajaxLogoSearch").show();`

Comment: It sounds like you're appending to the search results when you should be replacing them.

Comment: @JasonP yes this is my problem and I don't know how to don't duplicate the result

Comment: Maybe try `$("#innerSearch").empty()` before appending new results. You should also throttle the requests as suggested by KevinB too.

Comment: Logically you should abort the 1st ajax request and should wait for reply of 2nd ajax call. This is because 1st ajax will bring you search result for just single letter where as 2nd will give you back more narrowed result

Comment: So if i type out albert, it should start 6 ajax requests and abort 5 of them? why not just not send the 5 in the first place and only send the 6th?

Answer (score 2):

The better way is to simply not send a request until the user stops typing. this is easily done using the keydown event and a throttle waiting for 250ms of inactivity. Doing it your way will result in not getting the results that the user wants.

```
$("#search").on("keydown",function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    clearTimeout($this.data("throttle"));
    $this.data("throttle",setTimeout(function(){
        doSearch.call($this.get(0),$this.val()); // perform the ajax search
    },250))
});
```

Also, when inserting the new results, build the entire result list in a single variable then insert it all at once with .html(thehtml) after the loop.

Comment: what does *"the same problem"* mean? you have multiple problems. And the "problem" you are having may be due to how you implemented my solution.

Comment: I use your code but still I see duplicated data in search result

Comment: you're always going to get duplicated data unless you use the blur event, but that would be annoying to your users.

Comment: think about it. If you were searching for albert, and you typed "alb", paused for a moment, then typed "ert", you would get results for "alb", then it would find the results that match "albert". Obviously, some of the results from "alb" will also be returned with "albert" because all results from "albert" should also match "alb". the goal of a throttle is to only request when the user pauses or stops rather than requesting on every letter.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an additional variable kind of request. This variable will be store link of current ajax-request. When keyup event fire again you should do checking.

```
if(request) {
    request.abort();
}
request = $.ajax({/* */});
```

**UPD1:**  If first ajax-request completed you should set to zero request variable in success callback.

**UPD2:** Subscribe on change event is better

Comment: You should show examples of "UPD1" and "UPD2" This is not very clear.